# Unable to allow specific ip addresses in ufw

Tags: arch-linux, firewall, ufw

I am not able to get my `ufw` rules working. As far as I understand, the default behavior is to `deny` all incoming connections thus the command

```
ufw allow from 192.168.4.3 to any port http
```

should enable incoming http connections for the specific ip. However, the requests are blocked by the firewall. I've also tried to explicitly `deny` and then `allow` but it isn't working either.

The output of `ufw status verbose` is

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
631/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW IN    192.168.4.3                     
631/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

The output of `netstat -tulnp | grep :80` is

```
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 336/nginx: master p
```

Which part of the config / concept am I missing?

Comment: Can you include the output of 'ufw status verbose' above.

Comment: @Simon I've updated the question.

Comment: Are you sure you're being firewalled out, and the server is listening to port 80? does http / port 80 show as listening on a netstat? `netstat -tulnp | grep :80`

Comment: @RobotJohnny `nginx` is listening on the port. See the update above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the log `/var/log/ufw.log`. The default logging level (low) should record any blocked requests. Make sure the source IP (`SRC` field) matches the IP address you are expecting.

Comment: ufw logs to LOG_KERN syslog in my case. Yes, I've double checked the IP - nothing wrong there, they match.

Comment: hmm, `ufw deny from 192.168.4.3` is not working either.

Comment: Just to confirm, you can see the blocked requests in the log? If so, then I would suggest maybe flushing the existing rules and starting again. You could start by allowing everyone to access port 80 then narrow it down from there if that works. The order of the rules matters. The first one to match wins, so perhaps there is an earlier rule in a different chain that is blocking the request.

Answer (score 0):

You forget network mask. Try `ufw allow from 192.168.4.3/32 to any port http`

Comment: IMHO, that is just a longer syonym for the given IP. 32 bit netmask = zero range, single IP.

Comment: @sitilge yu're right.

Comment: @sitilge please share your network configuration. And output for `netstat -tldpn`.